# Allocate and initialize pointer in local function

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I want to allocate memory and fill it to the pointer, that are one of the function parameter, but I think that I don't get some important thing, help me please.

So, If I do that everything works fine:

```
void alloc(char **p, int n)
{
*p = new char[n];
}

int main() {
char * ptr = NULL;
int n = 10;
alloc(&ptr, n);
for(int i = 0; i<(n - 1); i++)
    ptr[i] = '1';
ptr[n - 1] = '\0';

printf("%s", ptr);
return 0;
}
```

Now I want to initialize the allocated memory also into the function

```
void alloc(char **p, int n)
{
*p = new char[n];
for(int i = 0; i<(n - 1); i++)
    *p[i] = '1';
*p[n - 1] = '\0';
} 

int main() {
char * ptr = NULL;
int n = 10;
alloc(&ptr, n); 
printf("%s", ptr);
return 0;
}
```

Program crashes. I don't get why. Please, can someone explain?

Comment: I'm not sure of the precedence of `*` vs `[]`. Try to declare a local `char *` maybe ?

Comment: It's excessive memory, below everyone give the right advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `(*p)[i]` and `(*p)[n - 1]` instead. The precedence rules cause `*p[i]` to be evaluated as `*(p[i])`.

Comment: it works, thanks! And this way to allocate memory is correct? I was told that it's incorrect because pointer doesn't point to anything..

Comment: @Alecs: It is correct. `ptr` does indeed not point to anything, but what you're passing to `alloc` is a pointer to `ptr`. So `*p` refers to `ptr` itself, not to whatever `ptr` points to. And since `*p = new char[n];` makes `ptr` point to something valid, it is now safe to use `*p` and `ptr` as arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
((*p)[i]) = '1';
```

you have a problem with operator's evaluation order.

Comment: it works, thanks! And this way to allocate memory is correct? I was told that it's incorrect because pointer doesn't point to anything.

Answer (score 2):

Probably  because this:

```
*p[i]
```

is interpreted as if you had written this:

```
*(p[i])
```

not as if you had written this, which is what you probably meant:

```
(*p)[i]
```

Comment: it works, thanks! And this way to allocate memory is correct? I was told that it's incorrect because pointer doesn't point to anything.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick,

```
void
alloc( char*& p, int n )
{
    p = new char[n];
    std::fill_n( p, n - 1, '1' );
    p[n - 1] = '\0';
}
```

If you insist on using a pointer as argument, change **all** of the `p`
in the function to `(*p)` (and don't forget to check for a null pointer
and do something reasonable if you're passed one.

All things considered, however, you'd be better off using
`std::string`—this function wouldn't even be necessary, as you
could write `std::string( n, '1' )`.

Comment: Yes, I also like C++ more than C, but now I have to work with C

Comment: Oh yes, I know, in this simple example it doesn't matter how to allocate, problem was in other thing, when I wrote it I automatically write it with new :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>   // for NULL

void alloc(char **p, int n)
{
    *p = new char[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<(n - 1); i++)
        *((*p) + i) = '1';
    *((*p) + n - 1) = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char * ptr = NULL;
    int n = 10;
    alloc(&ptr, n);
    printf("%s", ptr);

    // never forget delete pointers
    delete [] ptr;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: it works, thanks! And this way to allocate memory is correct? I was told that it's incorrect because pointer doesn't point to anything.

Answer (score 1):

Its a precedence of operators issue. Try this in your alloc function:

```
for(int i = 0; i<(n - 1); i++)
    (*p)[i] = '1';
(*p)[n - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: it works, thanks! And this way to allocate memory is correct? I was told that it's incorrect because pointer doesn't point to anything.